# Custom progress bar is cut in bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, progress-bar

I can't figure out what the problem is. I am trying to make this possible in every screen size but I'm stuck here.

This is the problem:

[image: linear layout]

the layout is big enough but the progress is cut there

[image: progress bar layout]

below there is the code. 
How can I fix it?

```
    ...
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <CustomProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarBPM"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <CustomProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarBPM2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    ...
```

The same code in two different phones:

[image: oneplus 6]
[image: motorola moto g]

Comment: Unless it displays fine when not inside a LinearLayout, it's probably something in the View itself.

Comment: @TheWanderer linear layout is not the problem. The problem is why the progress is cut with match parent and no margin set

Comment: set your height of linear layout to wrap_content and see if its occur.

Comment: @DennisTurri what's the View code, then?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH no difference

Comment: @TheWanderer the custom view is made from code. Do you want me to provide the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I was an issue from custom progress bar.